# Haskell : using guards after where

Tags: haskell, where-clause, let

Is it possible to use `guards` to define a function after a `where` is Haskell?

This works fine :

```
myMax a b = a + b - myMin a b
    where myMin a b = if a < b then a else b
```

But this

```
myMax a b = a + b - myMin a b
    where myMin a b
    | a < b      = a
    | otherwise  = b
```

will throw the following error message in ghci :

```
parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

on the line corresponding to `| a < b      = a`

Just as well, this will work :

```
myMax a b = 
  let myMin a b = if a < b then a else b  
  in  a + b - myMin a b
```

But this won't :

```
myMax a b = 
  let myMin a b 
    | a < b = b
    | otherwise = a 
  in  a + b - myMin a b
```

My guess would be that it's because using `guards` does not actually define a variable, even though it is required by the `where` and `let/in` structures? I am very new to Haskell so any explanation is greatly welcome!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to indent the guards past the declaration of your function:

```
myMax a b = a + b - myMin a b
    where myMin x y  -- Also, use different variable names here to avoid conflicts
            | x < y     = x
            | otherwise = y
```

Or as

```
myMax a b =
    let myMin x y
            | x < y     = x
            | otherwise = y
    in a + b - myMin a b
```

If you're using tabs for indentations, I would highly recommend to using spaces, they're less ambiguous with Haskell.  You can use tabs, but I see a lot of people run into parse errors because of it.

Comment: The thing about using tabs for indentation is that they're fine on their own, but mixing tabs and spaces leads to misleading situations (e.g. three spaces visually looks like much less indentation than two tabs but is actually more). And since your files will almost certainly include spaces, it's tabs that have to go.

Comment: I usually put `let` and `where` on their own lines unless the entire scope is going to fit easily on a single line.